# How to publish a WCF against a publish settings file?

Tags: wcf, azure, visual-studio-2013, publish

I have created a site in Azure and downloaded the publish settings file. When I click publish in VS I get the option to select a file with publish settings **but** only for the ASP.NET project. More or less [like so](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1286/how-do-i-deploy-visual-studio-2013-web-application-project-to-discountasp_net-server.aspx).

The problem is that I'm trying to publish a WCF library and the publish option allows only for IIS, FTP or system. I can't find an option for publishing via the settings file I've downloaded.

How can I point my WCF project to the PUBXML file?

## Edit

Based on the comments and replies, I also installed ASDK. Those are the projects I can choose now.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. This screenshot is from Visual Studio Community 2013.

[image]

and then...

[image]

.. then app.config additions for your addresses, bindings, and contracts

.. then Azure Endpoint configuration

Comment: The pictures - definite +1. App.config I think I can manage (at least for this POC I'll be doing - it can't differ much from the way I used before deploying the service under a web application). However, you're scaring me with the last part - Azure endpoint configuration. Is it something obvious once I get there? Or is a heads-up in place? (If it's a bit complicated, I recon that some pre-reading is often of help...)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to publish your library within a Worker Role and open an http endpoint through configuration.

you can also configure ASP.NET to host your WCF endpoint.  Again, just a bit of configuration needed for that.

Comment: Haven't used Worker Role before (up to now I've always had a website to show along with my WCFs so I never noticed that the publish differed, somehow). Is Worker Role something that's set up on Azure? There's a bunch of options on the left pane (including a cute elephant, I discovered - it wasn't there before).

Comment: You will need to install the Azure SDK (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) for your IDE and then create a new "Cloud Service" project.

Comment: I think I get it but I feel a bit uncertain. Please see the addition in the original question. Is that the correct service? Why are those two different?! It seems to me that, except for some small differences, a WCF service run as a web site (the way I've done before) and run as a cloud service should be the same in their architecture.